# TypeError: mock_input_output_start.<locals>.<lambda>() takes 1 positional argument

Tags: python, pytest, typeerror

Here is my line of code:

```
if change < 100:
    quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies = coin_calc(change)
    print(quarters, "quarter(s)")
    print(dimes, "dime(s)")
    print(nickels, "nickle(s)")
    print(pennies, "penny(ies)")
    print("Want to calculate another amount? (y/n): ", end="")
    answer = input()
    if answer == "n":
        print("Bye!")
        break
```

I get the error: TypeError: mock_input_output_start..() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

What can I do to fix this?

I tried:

```
 while True:
        change = input("Enter change amount to convert: ")
        if str(change).isnumeric():
            change = int(change)
            if change < 100:
                quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies = coin_calc(change)
                print(quarters, "quarter(s)")
                print(dimes, "dime(s)")
                print(nickels, "nickle(s)")
                print(pennies, "penny(ies)")
                print("Want to calculate another amount? (y/n): ", end="")
                answer = input()
                if answer == "n":
                    print("Bye!")
                    break
            else:
                print("Error! Invalid integer entered please try again.")
        else:
            print("Error! Invalid integer entered please try again.")


def coin_calc(change):
    quarters = change // 25
    change = change % 25
    dimes = change // 10
    change = change % 10
    nickels = change // 5
    change = change % 5
    pennies = change
    return quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies
```

Expecting a program to exchange coins.
I receive the TypeError

Comment: Please wrap your code snippets with a pair of lines containing just three backticks: `\`\`\``

Comment: what is `mock_input_output_start`? And where code of it and usage of it?

Comment: Indeed, your error seems to come from some function named  mock_input_output_start..() , which appears nowhere in the code you provided.